# Appium iOS Safari mobile browser emulator automation in Jenkins SauceLabs is giving error

Tags: jenkins, appium-ios, saucelabs

I am running a Safari mobile emulator test in Jenkins using SauceLabs Appium and getting error **Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.**

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

Capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    cap.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.20.1");
                    cap.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone X Simulator");
                    cap.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
                    cap.setCapability("browsername", "Safari");
                    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "14.3");
                    cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
                    cap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100);
                    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_NETWORK_CONNECTION, true);                    
                    webDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(
                            new URL("http://" + authentication.getUsername() + ":" + authentication.getAccessKey() + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
                            cap));
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'hvnplcbjwa22.gso.aexp.com', ip: '10.34.45.36', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {backendRetries: 4, bootstrapPath: /Volumes/Sauce/wda/wda-v1.2..., browserName: safari, browsername: Safari, databaseEnabled: false, derivedDataPath: /Volumes/Sauce/wda/wda-v1.2..., deviceName: iPhone X, eventTimings: true, hasMetadata: true, javascriptEnabled: true, keepKeyChains: true, launchTimeout: 180000, locationContextEnabled: false, maxTypingFrequency: 8, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 100, noReset: true, orientation: PORTRAIT, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 14.3, preventWDAAttachments: true, proxy: Proxy(pac: http://127.0.0.1..., showIOSLog: false, takesScreenshot: true, udid: C89AF4CE-54EF-4637-9DA3-B02..., usePrebuiltWDA: true, webStorageEnabled: false, webdriver.remote.quietExceptions: false, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 8c723adc6e3f4270b2fac4c8a9f...}
Session ID: 8c723adc6e3f4270b2fac4c8a9fe489a
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by flushing the proxy tunnels to Saucelabs